# How to exclude ADF auto generated properties from Web activity

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a web activity in ADF pipeline. This web activity calls an API and get data from that. The output Web activity is in below format,

```
{
  "fdgdhgfh": {
    "so2_production": 7hjhgj953,
    "battery_charge": jkjlkj,
    "battery_discharge": kjlklj,
    "critical_load_energy": 4ljljh4
},
  "9fsdsfb": {   
    "so2_production": asdasd,
    "battery_charge": sdaasf,
    "battery_discharge": ewewrwer,
    "critical_load_energy": bmvkbjk
  },
"ADFWebActivityResponseHeaders":{
"Content-Length":14268,
"Content-Type":"application/json"
},
"effectiveIntegrationRunTime":"Azure IR",
"billingReference":{
"activityType":"ExternalActivity"
},
}
```

From above output I only want API response without ADF auto generated properties like,

```
{
  "fdgdhgfh": {
    "so2_production": 7hjhgj953,
    "battery_charge": jkjlkj,
    "battery_discharge": kjlklj,
    "critical_load_energy": 4ljljh4
  },
  "9fsdsfb": {
   
    "so2_production": asdasd,
    "battery_charge": sdaasf,
    "battery_discharge": ewewrwer,
    "critical_load_energy": bmvkbjk
  }
}
```

Let me know the process or expression to achieve in ADF pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Since you are not getting the `response` attribute in the set variable activity, you can use the following procedure instead.
- Store the output of `web activity` output as a string in a variable using set variable activity. The output would look like something shown below:

[image]

- Now, use another set variable activity to split the above string using `ADFWebActivityResponseHeaders` as delimiter.

```
@split(variables('tp2'),'ADFWebActivityResponseHeaders')[0]
```

[image]

- Finally, using the following dynamic content in another set variable activity, I was able to extract required part:

```
@array(json(substring(variables('tp1'),0,sub(length(variables('tp1')),3))))
```

[image]

- I have taken it as an array for demonstration. You can access the required part from this using the dynamic content `@variables('tp3')[0]` where tp3 is the variable with value in the above image.

Comment: Refer the Json which I have shared in question. That is how I am getting output from ADF web activity. It is coming as an object not an array. It does not have a **Response** object.  That is the issue. I can't select response/ value from output of web activity as it is an object and not an array.

Comment: Updated the answer accordingly. Check if it helps.